# Mongoose how to refer to the same schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So my problem statement is something like this:
   -I have this schema of an object

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
     unique: true,
     minlength: 1,
     maxlength: 100
 },
 parent: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'categorySchema'
 }
});
```

- that parent field should refer to the same schema, but when i want to populate i get this error ( here I know that field parent is on that object )

```
error: MongooseError [MissingSchemaError]: Schema hasn't been registered for model "categorySchema".
```

- and another problem would be, how I can check if that field 'parent' is on the object when I make a query to get all object from that table then populate it. I know manually how to do it, but is there any simpler way?

Thank you!

Comment: You have to put the name that you pass to mongoose.model() as the first parameter. I still don't get your question, please provide the manual way that you try to simplify

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate refer this for more details